# ping: connect network is unreacheble arch linux

Tags: arch-linux, dhcp, ping

I'm new to arch linux

I haven't installed Arch yet, but that's my problem.

When I run ping 1.1.1.1 or ping 8.8.8.8, I get an error...

The following error appears:

```
ping: connect: Network is unreachable
```

My connection type is by ethernet
I made a bootable usb wit the ArchISO and i followed the the procedures of Arch Linux Installation Guide!
When i reached "Connecting the internet" i made the ping comnmand! But didn't work (the error is above)
Here what i tried:
ip link set enp30s0 up

I tried the ip link command to see what my ethernet controller is called. It's called enp30s0.

So I tried dhcpcd enp30s0 but I got a weird error:

```
Failed to set DNS configuration: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.network1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)

Failed to revert interface configuration: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.network1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
time out
```

I didn't try that much (true) but as i said, i'm new!!!
I don't know what's going on

I am not using a virtual machine

I have the following components:

two discs:
sda 237 GB (which has Windows 10 installed)

sdb 465 GB (which is where I want to install Arch Linux)

If you could help me I would appreciate it!

PS: I'm totally new to arch linux so I hope the problem is easy to solve :(

Comment: Welcome on U&L! _"I haven't installed Arch yet"_: did you boot off an Arch ISO image? Are you following the [Installation guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Installation_guide)? It will likely be easier to help you if we can understand what procedure you are following, what did you do and where you are stuck at.

Comment: i just edited my question

Comment: i added what is tried. But i didn't tried to much, because like i said, im new!

Comment: Thank you! I'd suggest you to add your system's hardware model and network card model to your question. Then, to understand what's going on, you can try: `lspci -v`, looking for a block relating to your ethernet card and particularly the "Kernel driver in use" and "Kernel modules" lines; `journalctl -b 0 -u systemd-networkd -u systemd-resolved` to inspect the logs about the networking-related services, looking for errors; `ip addr` to see how your network interface is configured. You may add these commands' output to your question if you feel it's relevant or if you are not sure.

Comment: _(continued)_ Finally, to make sure about the basic stuff: is there a DHCP server on the network your card is connected to (and are you sure it is working)?

Comment: @fra-san i don't think i have DHCP server

Comment: I will try the commands that you sayed to get all the basic information :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem!

In my computer I have a USB internet card too...
When I started the USB bootable medium a message appeared saying:

```
rtl_usb: reg 0x80, usbctrl_vendorreq Time out! status: 0xffffff92 value=0xa500
```

Then I read the error with more attention and I disconnected the USB internet card, and it worked!